# Is there a webapp which let's me email stuff to my colleagues, and they receive a daily summary of those emails?

Tags: email, project-management

It should also archive the content of those emails in some sort of private online feed, for easy reference.

I'm going to use it to notify them of new rules and coding conventions we're going to use. Having the conventions also stored in a central place would give me the ability to have new employees just read through that list.

I've seen one before where the whole team submits their tasks and everyone gets a summary email. But I can't remember the name of it. :(

Comment: I found the one which I couldn't remember: https://idonethis.com/

It doesn't do exactly what I need though, so the question is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Groups will allow you to send emails to any number of people. Those people can elect to receive each email, or a daily digest. Groups can be invite-only, and you can prevent other group members from sending email if you wish.

The emails are always viewable online later. If you always reply to the same subject line, they will be readable in one long thread; otherwise you can use subject lines to separate by topic.

Comment: Excellent! I'm amazed that never crossed my mind :)